# My SSE/AVX optimization for element-wise sqrt is no boosting, why

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, simd

I'm new to SIMD optimization, trying to calculate each element's sqrt value for a 1D float array.

System: Windows 10
Compiler: Visual Studio 2017
CPU:  Intel Core i5-8500

The follwoing code is compiled and run under Release mode, however **the normal (naive) implementaion is nearly the same speed as the SSE and AVX optimized version**. Don't know why. Is my implementaion or the method that I do performance is wrong?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "nmmintrin.h" // SSE4.2
#include "immintrin.h"  // for AVX

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename P>
std::string toString(std::chrono::duration<T,P> dt)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    str << duration_cast<microseconds>(dt).count()*1e-3 << " ms";
    return str.str();
}

template<typename _Tp> static inline _Tp* alignPtr(_Tp* ptr, int n = (int)sizeof(_Tp))
{
    return (_Tp*)(((size_t)ptr + n - 1) & -n);
}

typedef unsigned char uchar;
#define MALLOC_ALIGN 16

void* fast_malloc(size_t size);
void fast_free(void* ptr);

void* fast_malloc(size_t size) {
    uchar* udata = (uchar*)malloc(size + sizeof(void*) + MALLOC_ALIGN);
    if (!udata) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to allocate memory\n");
        assert(0);
    }
    uchar** adata = alignPtr((uchar**)udata + 1, MALLOC_ALIGN);
    adata[-1] = udata;
    return adata;
}

void fast_free(void* ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        uchar* udata = ((uchar**)ptr)[-1];
        assert(udata < (uchar*)ptr &&
            ((uchar*)ptr - udata) <= (ptrdiff_t)(sizeof(void*) + MALLOC_ALIGN));
        free(udata);
    }
}


//element-wise squar root of an array, normal impl
void ew_sqrt_normal(float* a, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = sqrt(a[i]);
    }
}


//element-wise squar root of an array, sse impl
void ew_sqrt_sse(float* a, int N) {
    int iters = N / 4;
    __m128* ptr = (__m128*)a;
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++, ptr++, a += 4) {
        _mm_store_ps(a, _mm_sqrt_ps(*ptr));
    }
}


//element-wise squar root of an array, sse impl
void ew_sqrt_avx(float* a, int N) {
    int iters = N / 8;
    __m256* ptr = (__m256*)a;
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++, ptr++, a += 8) {
        _mm256_store_ps(a, _mm256_sqrt_ps(*ptr));
    }
}


int main(){
    volatile int num_elem = 1024 * 1024 * 3;
    size_t size = num_elem * sizeof(float);
    float* data = (float*)fast_malloc(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elem; i++) {
        data[i] = i + 1;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //float* data1 = (float*)fast_malloc(size);
        float* data1 = (float*)fast_malloc(size);
        memcpy(data1, data, size);
        const auto t1_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        ew_sqrt_normal(data1, num_elem);
        const auto t1_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();


        float* data2 = (float*)fast_malloc(size);
        memcpy(data2, data, size);
        const auto t2_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        ew_sqrt_sse(data2, num_elem);
        const auto t2_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();


        float* data3 = (float*)fast_malloc(size);
        memcpy(data3, data, size);
        const auto t3_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        ew_sqrt_avx(data3, num_elem);
        const auto t3_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();


        cout << i + 1 << "-th perf, got: " << endl;
        cout << "normal: " << toString(t1_end - t1_start) << endl;
        cout << "sse:    " << toString(t2_end - t2_start) << endl;
        cout << "avx:    " << toString(t3_end - t3_start) << endl;
        cout << endl;

        fast_free(data1);
        fast_free(data2);
        fast_free(data3);
    }

    fast_free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

The perf result:

```
1-th perf, got:
normal: 1.101 ms
sse:    0.997 ms
avx:    1.034 ms

2-th perf, got:
normal: 1.098 ms
sse:    0.868 ms
avx:    0.823 ms

3-th perf, got:
normal: 1.018 ms
sse:    0.927 ms
avx:    0.878 ms

4-th perf, got:
normal: 0.802 ms
sse:    1.113 ms
avx:    0.759 ms

5-th perf, got:
normal: 0.886 ms
sse:    0.879 ms
avx:    0.757 ms

6-th perf, got:
normal: 0.815 ms
sse:    0.918 ms
avx:    0.922 ms

7-th perf, got:
normal: 0.852 ms
sse:    0.786 ms
avx:    0.796 ms

8-th perf, got:
normal: 0.809 ms
sse:    0.874 ms
avx:    0.763 ms

9-th perf, got:
normal: 0.884 ms
sse:    1.442 ms
avx:    0.877 ms

10-th perf, got:
normal: 0.864 ms
sse:    0.802 ms
avx:    0.999 ms
```

**update1**

Just forgot to mention the optimization level I'm using. It's cmake generated Visual Studio project, using **O2 optimization.**

Also tested: switching to O1 level optimization, normal implementation decreate to 10 ms, which is very obvious slower. Thanks for @Peter Cordes 's comment.

**update2**
In my PC, in VS2019, x64 mode, the full command options when choosing /O1 optimization, is:

```
/permissive- /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O1 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Switch to /O2 optimization, it is:

```
/permissive- /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

The only difference is the `/O1` and `/O2`.

By looking [MSDN's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o1-o2-minimize-size-maximize-speed?view=vs-2019), we can see:

```
/O1 (Minimize Size) /Og /Os /Oy /Ob2 /GF /Gy
/O2 (Maximize Speed)    /Og /Oi /Ot /Oy /Ob2 /GF /Gy
```

Comment: Did your compiler auto-vectorize the scalar version?  `a[i] = sqrt(a[i]);` should vectorize easily with modern compilers.  Try it with `gcc -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize`, or whatever the equivalent is for MSVC.  Possibly optimize for size over speed?  (Does MSVC call that `-O1`?)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was using /O2, which is given by cmake, on default. Switch to /O1 makes `normal` slow down.

Comment: Yeah, normally you should build with full optimization to let the compiler make fast code when it knows how.  That shows there's nothing to be gained from manually vectorizing this loop.

Comment: In MSVC 2019 /O1 and /O2 result in identical performance. The first version is auto-vectorized to `sqrtps` and becomes identical to the SSE version. BTW have you seen `_aligned_malloc` and `_aligned_free`?

Comment: @rustyx I test in MSVC 2019, /O1 and /O2 result different performance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your first loop was optimized away. I forced keeping it by adding a cout statement with a random index.

Typical result:

```
normal: 9.203 ms
sse:    0.814 ms
avx:    0.678 ms
```

Interestingly, even after enabling automatic vectorization, the `normal` time does not improve.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing I see, is that you're using serveral memory copys. you can leave those aside by defining a union:

```
union f64_m256{
double f[4];
__m256d m; 
}
```

now every object of type f64_m256 occupies the same memory location (the types share the same 256 bits).
You can now do for example:

```
//build x as a combined type - builds first the array
f64_m256 x = {1.,2.,3.,4.}; 

//calculate the sqrt via simd and return it to x 
x.m = _mm256_sqrt_pd(x.m);

//access the calculated sqrts
cout << x.f[2] << endl;
```

this saves you some unnecessary copies and can be applied to pretty much every simd instruction.

The trick is to access the memory in x in the manner that is convinient to you/ is right for the function (as an _m256d or array of doubles).

Comment: I saw some tutorial mentioning your pasted coding style. It's helpful for understanding while it doesn't eliminate data copy. See my pasted code, the sse/avx implementation, a pointer is passed to those funtions, and type casting is employed, and no data copy inside them. What I do data copy in main(), is to keep 3 implementations with exactly same input data.

Comment: What sense does it make to improve the sections of the test program that are not timed ?